# MySQL group_concat query help needed

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a MySQL database.I have a table which contains say list of procedures and estimated time suggested by different developers.

As follows:

```
proc_name   user_id    est_time
-------------------------------
'A'           1           20
'A'           3           15
'B'           2           16
'B'           4           18
'C'           1           20
```

Now I need output something like this

```
A|1_20|2_0 |3_15|4_0
B|1_20|2_16|3_0 |4_18
C|1_20|2_0 |3_0 |4_0
```

If user is not posting any hours for a `proc_name`, '0' will be printed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't "group_concat".  This is an example of pivoting.

```
select proc_name,
       concat('1_', max(case when user_id = 1 then est_time else 0 end)),
       concat('2_', max(case when user_id = 2 then est_time else 0 end)),
       concat('3_', max(case when user_id = 3 then est_time else 0 end)),
       concat('4_', max(case when user_id = 4 then est_time else 0 end))
from t
group by proc_name
```

I find it strange, though, that you are putting all the user 1's in the first column *and* also putting the the "1" in the column value.

Actually, if you really want the data as a single string, then you can concatenate the above results together rather than putting them in separate columns:

```
select concat_ws('|', proc_name,
                 concat('1_', max(case when user_id = 1 then est_time else 0 end)),
                 concat('2_', max(case when user_id = 2 then est_time else 0 end)),
                 concat('3_', max(case when user_id = 3 then est_time else 0 end)),
                 concat('4_', max(case when user_id = 4 then est_time else 0 end))
                )
from t
group by proc_name
```